How to convert text to hyperlinks without VBA?
We have a template with a dropdown list.  The end-user selects from the list and a hyperlink should be inserted into the document body (at the cursor).  problem is, the hyperlink is coming in as plain text. The end-user must then click at the end of the hyperlink and press the spacebar.  Only then the autocorrect kicks in and converts the text into a true hyperlink.
Is there anything in Word I can do to find/replace or convert the plain text to Hyperlink?
I'm not allowed to use VBA.

You can achieve the conversion of plain text URL to hyperlinks by following these suggestions.

Turn on AutoFormat as You Type: Go to File > Options, Select Proofing and the click on AutoCorrect Options, Go to the AutoFormat as You Type tab then chekc the box labeled Internet and network paths with hyperlinks
Use Find and Replace: Press Crtl+H to opne FInd and replace, then in the Find What type the Url you are wanting to replace and in the Replace with enter the same URL again. Then finally click Replace All


thank you for your prompt reply.  Those two options are the only thing I could think of.  Since we're talking about only one link per document and since it's on the first page, clicking at the end of the text and pressing spacebar is the quickest option so far.  Again apologies for the stupid question, but I was completely out of ideas and you folks always come through.
